# Get XML nodes attributes and set as properties of List<myType>?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Example XML:

```
<Root>
 <Product value="Candy">
    <Item value="Gum" price="1.00"/>
    <Item value="Mints" price="0.50"/>
 </Product>
</Root>
```

Let's say I have a class with properties:

```
public class CandyItems
{
  public string Value{get; set;}
  public string Price{get; set;}
}
```

And within my main program class, I have a list:

```
var Candies = new List<CandyItems>;
```

I am struggling with a concise way to populate the `Candies` list, using LINQ.

I could do it in steps, like this:

```
//Get list of Items within <Product value="Candy">
XElement tempCandies = XDocument.Load("file.xml").Root.Elements("Product").Single(c => c.Attributes("value") == "Candy").Descendants("Item");

//Loop through the elements
foreach(var item in tempCandies){
  Candies.Add(new CandyItems{Value = item.Attributes("value"), Price = item.Attributes("price")});
}
```

But it seems like I could do this more concisely with pure LINQ somehow. Or is there another recommended method?

Comment: How about using [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"Path\Candies.xml");
List<CandyItems> Candies = xdoc.Descendants("Item")
                               .Select(x => new CandyItems
                                      {
                                         Value = (string)x.Attribute("value"),
                                         Price = (string)x.Attribute("price")
                                      }).ToList();
```

Although, you have not mentioned but if you want to just fetch Candies and your XML may contain other products too like:-

```
<Root>
  <Product value="Candy">
    <Item value="Gum" price="1.00"/>
    <Item value="Mints" price="0.50"/>
  </Product>
  <Product value="Chocolate">
    <Item value="MilkChocolate" price="7.00"/>
    <Item value="DarkChocolate" price="10.50"/>
  </Product>
</Root>
```

Then you can apply a filter to fetch only `Candy` products like this:-

```
List<CandyItems> Candies = xdoc.Descendants("Item")
                              .Where(x => (string)x.Parent.Attribute("value") == "Candy")
                              .Select(x => new CandyItems
                                     {
                                        Value = (string)x.Attribute("value"),
                                        Price = (string)x.Attribute("price")
                                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (after loading the document):

```
var candies = 
    xdoc.Root.Elements("Product")
        .Where(p => p.Attribute("value").Value == "Candy")
        .SelectMany(p => p.Descendants("Item").Select(i => new CandyItems { 
             Value = i.Attribute("value").Value, 
             Price = i.Attribute("price").Value }));
```

Note: any and all error handling omitted.